# Correspondence between morphism and ring of regular functions

Tags: algebraic-geometry

in Hartshorne it is explained that an morphism of varieties $\varphi:X \to Y$ gives rise to $k$-algebra-homomorphism of $O(Y) \to O(X)$. Now I know by the defining property of morphism that a morphism carries a regular function $f$ on open $V\subset Y$ to a regular function on $\varphi^{-1}(V)$ by $f\circ \varphi$ for all open subsets $V\subset Y$. In particular given $f\in O(Y)$ we have $f\circ \varphi :\varphi^{-1} (V)\to k$ regular. Question: Why is this a regular function on $X$?
If $\varphi$ is an isomorphism it makes sense for me, but here $f\circ \varphi$ need not even to be defined (as a regular function) on the whole of $X$.

Thanks for your kind help!

Comment: I find it helpful to think of a regular map from affine $X \to Y \subset A^n$ as $n$ polynomials $f = (f_1, \ldots, f_n)$ , such that $f(X) \subset Y$, Hartshorne proves these are equivalent later in the chapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have any function $\varphi : X \to Y$ whatsoever, then $\varphi^{-1}(Y) = X$, since each point of $X$ gets mapped to *some* point of $Y$.